# Is war started by one person or a country?

Tags: political-philosophy

When someone declares war on a country it is a leader that rules the country that declares war. The leader that declares war is usually in charge because they are elected so the country chose them to have the right to choose, but when people disagree, they themselves have trusted the leader to be in charge. With different opinions of the people in the country, and lives being one of the highest currencies, war is still declared. So is war started by one person or a country?

Comment: Countries are abstract ideas. They don't have wills. They don't "want" things, "start" things. For that, you need an agent with free will. Now, a war is formally declared by a governor or governing body of some country or other, but in the case you describe, where that person or body is democratically elected, that declaration must match the prevailing will of a sufficient number of individuals in the populace. So the question is kind of moot. The answer is "yes".

Comment: There's an interesting question about how countries at war relate to their people and leaders somewhere in here. There's also some extra claims that are assumptions and should be made clear: (1) the claim that lives are one of the highest currencies. (2) a claim about the relationship between the leader and the people ...

Comment: The people who voted to close (reason: off-topic) seem to know very little of philosophy. At my department there is even a research project about collective decisions. Whether there are such things is an unsettled question, but if there are, maybe the decision to go to war (via electing the president for example) is an interesting case. Closing a question that is being debated right now by philosophers as off-topic seems to me to be mad.

Comment: @Lukas, I haven't voted to close this question, but I don't think it's an especially good question. While I agree that collected action is a hot topic in some realms of contemporary philosophy, this question doesn't seem to cut at the issue especially well. There's some jarring twists in the way it's worded and it seems to arbitrarily bring up certain values without making them clear. Or to put it another way, it's collective action + value claims + something about disagreement + life as a currency. Then the basic question of collective action again.

Comment: I think the issues that the question brings up are important; but the way it's worded isn't great which might explain the close votes

Comment: The close-votes claim that the question is off-topic, and thats stupid. I didn't say anything about how good or bad this question is, just that it is a contemporary philosophical question and as such, not off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Despite your question is a bit ambiguous, to me it seems to imply that you mean by "war" an armed conflict between sovereign countries. Then of course the person who declares war, does it only in its role as a e.g. leader of that country. Therefor not the person qua person declares war, but the the country declares war through the voice of its leader.

Answer (score 0):

War is a political concept. War is something that a country does when its constitution says "this is the set of conditions under which a war happens." There might be things that don't fit that technical definition, but are practically similar to wars. You might call those wars, or "armed conflicts," or whatever... But the basic idea of war is just that it's a construct of how countries interact with one another.

You might say that, for some countries, one individual leader has the authority to declare war, but that would only be as a function of the country's processes. You can ask whether it's my brain or heart that thinks (obviously, my brain), but if you're asking whether *I'm* thinking, yes, I am. So if a subset of the country is given authority to declare war on the country's behalf, the country has declared war.

To be clear, in the United States, no one person can ever declare war. Only congress can declare war, and that involves many people.

You might also ask whether I, as an ordinary citizen and civilian, am a party to that war, or am morally responsible for the war. But the country definitely declared the war, and went to war.